# PySpark StandardScaler throwing error on double column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a DataFrame with a column named `value` with the following schema type:

```
(...)
|-- value: double (nullable = true)
(...)
```

When I try to fit the `StandardScaler`, such as:

```
scaler = StandardScaler(inputCol="mean",
                        outputCol="mean_standardized",
                        withStd=True, withMean=False)
scaler.fit(df)
```

It throws the following error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: 'requirement failed: Column value must be of type struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>> but was actually double.'
```

Which seems to be a problem with the `double` type of the column, what is the expected column type for `StandardScaler` ?

*I'm using Spark 2.4.3 with Hadoop 2.7.*

Comment: Can you share a sample DataFrame which you are trying to work with? It seems like you would need a struct type.

Comment: Thanks, I found the issue, the `StandardScaler` requires a `Vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. The `StandardScaler` requires a type `Vector` for it to work. You just have to wrap your columns into `Vector`.

Comment: Hello could you post your solution code here and mark this as solved. I've the same problem.